# how to calculate the volume of water from shower sprinkler required for sodden total human body

Tags: volume

I want to know how to calculate the volume of water (with respect to water flow and shower sprinkler geometry) required to sodden human body from head to feet for a human getting shower with sprinkler.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) Please note that this is **not** a homework help site. Please show your work and ask about a specific physics concept.

Comment: Jafarino, my apologies, I misread your question. The answer is  that a 5 minute shower requires 30 litres of water, assuming the shower delivers 6 litres a minute. Every extra minute in the shower will use 6 litres of water.

Comment: You won't get a precise answer if you can't precisely say what "sodden" means.  People don't soak up water the way sponges do.

Answer (score 2):

The average adult has about eight pounds (3.6 kilograms), or about 22 square feet (2 square meters) of skin. It may help to put that in perspective -- a standard doorway is 21 square feet, and the average adult's skin would fill all of that space.

It's just the wetted area you need.

So how much water do you need to complete cover 2 square meters of skin to  a depth of 1 cm.

EDIT

From the comments below and from reading the question **properly**, the answer is, based on the assumption that the average electric shower delivers six litres a minute, a 5 minute shower uses 30 litres.

My sincere apologies to the OP for misreading the question.

END EDIT

Comment: Thank you very much count_to_10 for you answer, but unfortunately  I not arrived to understand how to calculate the water exposure volume, I need this for making a study about impact of hydrotherapy on human health.